# How to set first day of week and last day of week to be white colour?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am trying to achieve a calendar which the first days of the week and last days of the week would be coloured differently. Now I can colour the todays day, event days and the days normally, however, I am getting stuck how to compare if a "Day" is the first day of the week.

I have this function:

```java
    /**
     * This method is used to set a color of texts, font types and backgrounds of TextView objects
     * in a current visible month. Visible day labels from previous and forward months are set using
     * setDayColors() method. It also checks if a day number is a day number of today and set it
     * a different color and bold face type.
     *
     * @param day                A calendar instance representing day date
     * @param today              A calendar instance representing today date
     * @param dayLabel           TextView containing a day numberx
     * @param calendarProperties A resource of a color used to mark today day
     */
    public static void setCurrentMonthDayColors(Calendar day, Calendar today, TextView dayLabel,
                                                CalendarProperties calendarProperties) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Day: " + day);
        if (today.equals(day)) {
            setDayColors(dayLabel, calendarProperties.getTodayLabelColor(), Typeface.BOLD,
                    R.drawable.background_transparent);
        } else if (EventDayUtils.isEventDayWithLabelColor(day, calendarProperties)) {
            EventDayUtils.getEventDayWithLabelColor(day, calendarProperties).executeIfPresent(eventDay ->
                DayColorsUtils.setDayColors(dayLabel, eventDay.getLabelColor(),
                        Typeface.NORMAL, R.drawable.background_transparent));

        } else if (calendarProperties.getHighlightedDays().contains(day)) {
            setDayColors(dayLabel, calendarProperties.getHighlightedDaysLabelsColor(),
                    Typeface.NORMAL, R.drawable.background_transparent);
        } else if (day.equals(GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek())) {
            setDayColors(dayLabel, Color.WHITE, Typeface.BOLD,
                    R.drawable.background_transparent);
        } else {
            setDayColors(dayLabel, calendarProperties.getDaysLabelsColor(), Typeface.BOLD,
                    R.drawable.background_transparent);
        }
    }
```

Now in this else if:

```java
else if (day.equals(GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getFirstDayOfWeek())) {
            setDayColors(dayLabel, Color.WHITE, Typeface.BOLD,
                    R.drawable.background_transparent);
```

I am trying to compare if the day we are setting right now is the first day of the week, however, every time I try to compare I get that you can compare calendar object to int. From the Logs, I can tell that the "day" object has a field which states which day of the week it is:

`DAY_OF_WEEK=1`

It should, by the idea check if that value is the first day if it is set it to be white colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this :

```java
 else if (day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY ||
                day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
            setDayColors(dayLabel, Color.WHITE, Typeface.NORMAL,
                    R.drawable.background_transparent);
```